# How does the Steins;Gate phone microwave work?

Tags: steins-gate

The operation of the phone microwave in Steins;Gate is confusing me. I finished episode 9, and I don't fully understand how it works; except that it allows texts to be sent in the past, 1 second on timer = 1 hour in reality, and that messages can only be sent during 12pm-6pm.

Can someone explain the rest of the microwaves' operation?

1) the bananas turning green, and why the first green batch wouldn't transport?

2) why did Mayuri's chicken tenders burn? can food be cooked like normal, or is their microwave permanently modified?

3) why a phone is hooked up to the microwave, what is the significance in connecting it, and why is it no longer needed in future episodes?

4) in reference to question 3, what type of connection was the phone connected by? USB?

5) why does the timer always seem to be set to 120?

6) what do the orange numerals above the timer numerals mean?

7) how is data sent? how are objects sent?

8) what is the cause of the electrical discharge? and why does it appear at different intervals?

9) is there significance behind the rotation of the microwave table? does clockwise move time forward, and vice versa?

10) how is a modern day text message able to be routed to a 90s pager?

11) what is the large flat radio device sitting on top of the microwave, and what is its purpose?

12) what the heck is a CRT (Cathode Ray Tube)? the landlord wears clothing with CRT related phrases on them

Comment: Can you shorten down your list of questions into a single question, or the main things you want to know? Currently it's hard for an answer to answer all of your questions in detail because there's so many

Comment: Realistically, you have nine complete questions here: 1&2, 3&4, 5, 6, 7&10, 8, 9, and 11. Question 12 is Googleable. Having nine questions here precludes a lot of possibilities for people who can answer eight or less of them.

Answer (score 0):

I will leave out anything that is related to further in the anime.

1- they went green because they entered the blackhole that was created, but were spat out again in the same place as no "space/time coordinates were sent (ie a phonenumber)

3- as far I can tell it is always needed up until Okabe does something "different".

4- it is in a dock stand probably hard wired manually into the circuitry on the microwave

5- lazy animation

6- date time

8- PLOT

Quite easily, as long as they know the phonenumber as pagers worked alot like texts do these days.

12 - Cathode ray tubes is what Old Televisions used to create images, I wont go into any detail so google this.

Comment: You can use the spoiler tags >! in the editor if you would like to reference the other items